# PhpMyAdmin Issue 'phpmyadmin.pma_table_uiprefs' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I am using PHPMyAdmin to manage MySql.
When I installed PHPMyAdmin in new machine.
This worked and I have many databases imported. When I open any Tables from Database.It showing an error `#1146 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma_table_uiprefs' doesn't exist`

I have attached the screenshot. Please refer if you need.

I had gone through [doc](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#phpmyadmin-configuration-storage).

And also I have checked related issues.

Tried below steps:

- On the shell: locate create_tables.sql.
- import /usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/examples/create_tables.sql.gz using 
  phpMyAdmin.
- open /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php and edit lines 81-92:    change
  pma_bookmark to pma__bookmark and so on.

But not yet resolved. 
It would be great if anyone can suggest any improvements or updations.

Thanks in Advance

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Just import create_tables.sql in ..\phpMyAdmin\sql

Answer (score 0):

Same problem has solved by clear the phpmyadmin session data. It works for me. Under the phpmyadmin logo there is a icon "Empty seesion data". Hope it will works.